# After decoupling code, what to do when class libraries utilize the same code?

Tags: c#, decoupling

I've been working steadily on decoupling my project into the main console application, and a couple class libraries.

It's an OWIN based server which hosts communication between a custom Alexa Skill and it's endpoints. This utilizes JSON communication.

My application also communicates with Microsoft Azure FaceAPI, which also utilizes JSON communication.

Finally, the application also uses JSON to retrieve and save settings for a web-based configuration UI.

This means there are three class libraries and the main console program which utilize NewtonsoftJson to serialize and deserialize JSON data.

I have created a helper Class which handles all of the serializations.

However, in order to keep the class libraries decoupled, and reusable in other applications, this would mean I would have to have the same Helper Class show up in each ClassLibrary.

On their own, it seems okay that each Class Library has the code in it.

But, it looks like a bunch of repeated code when I see the class in the Solution Explorer inside all the ClassLibraries and the main application.

Is it typical, when decoupling code, to reuse classes in this way?

Maybe the JSON Helper should be its own ClassLibrary?

The class libraries are dependent on NewtonSoft already so it would seem silly to create another dependency... confused.

Maybe it is okay to repeat code like this??

EDIT: My helper class will hold methods like this:

```
  public string SerializeToString(object obj)
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter((streamWriter)))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, obj);
            }
            return streamWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

they can then be called like:

```
return new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer().SerializeToString(directiveResponse)
```

where NewtonsoftJsonSerializer is the helper class name.

Methods like the one posted above are used in my AlexaApi,MircosoftFaceApi, and Configuration ClassLibraries.

Comment: What exactly does the helper class do? I'm picturing one line of code calling `serializer.Serialize()`. If the helper class has knowledge of the class to serialize, why is it duplicate code and not specific to the Skill or FaceAPI library? Please provide some code.

Comment: I am bit confused, are you creating separate project for serialization purpose? If it's so, it'll just add complexity if you'll add like this. I think, you need to use inheritance/polymorphism approach to deal with this problem which requires one project for all serialization stuff.

Comment: I added some code snippets in the OP from my help class to better explain what my plan of attack is.

Comment: I've decided to do away with the helper class and use the function and methods from the class in each class library where I need them.

Comment: why not just write ```JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)``` that will give you a string

Comment: Yes JsonConvert.SerializeObject is perfect! Many thanks!